# Get the last modified date of a directory (including subdirectories) using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the last modification date and time of a directory. while doing that I want to include the last modified date of the sub directories as well.

I could find some topics related to this question.([How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)) but all of those just gives the last modified time of the root directory without considering the sub directories.

```
import os.path, time
print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
print "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))
```

These lines of code just gives the last modified time of the root directory without considering the sub directories. 
Please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "include"? Do you want a `list` of times, one per subdirectory? Or do you want the most recent mod time of a directory hierarchy?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion, I want the most recent mod time of a directory hierarchy?

Comment: Then you should walk that directory hierarchy (see `os.walk()`), collecting mod times as you go. Select the most recent one with `max()`. I'll create an example if you need it.

Comment: thanks for the idea, if you give me an example that would be great.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should do what you ask:

```
import os
import time

print time.ctime(max(os.stat(root).st_mtime for root,_,_ in os.walk('/tmp/x')))
```

But I see you use `os.path.getmtime()`. So you are probably looking for this:

```
print time.ctime(max(os.path.getmtime(root) for root,_,_ in os.walk('/tmp/x')))
```

Comment: Doesn't linux do this book-keeping? I thought a directory's modification time was updates with its children.

Comment: No, a directory's mod time only reflects modifications to the directory file (i.e. additions and deletions of entries). So /tmp/x is updated when /tmp/x/foo.txt is created, but not when /tmp/x/y/foo.txt is. (And, of course, /tmp/x is also not updated when /tmp/x/foo.txt is merely modified.)

Comment: Is this only for Linux or would this work on other OS's?

Comment: While the original post only asked about subdirectories, I think its possible the OP may have also been interested in the age of files within the directory.  I just want to point out that this answer does not consider file modification times.